# Detecting when an object with surface mount component?

Tags: sensor, infrared, proximity-sensor, ultrasound

We have a pcb that sits close to some hole. When something passes through ( at 2-5cm distance) we have to detect it.

To me it seems that this area is still in the 90's . When I check my options, all of them are large modules of **infra red** devices, or **ultrasonic** modules.

These works great, but I was looking for something that can *sit on the pcb*, small, and simply detect light/sound/etc.

Something elegant , the size of a chip.

Are there things like that ?

Comment: Yes, there are plenty. Chip-scale IR distance sensors. You probably have one in your phone for detecting if the cover is closed.

Comment: Thanks, but those in the phone have a very limited angle, because they are usually phototransistors, you can't put them in day light and measure when something passes by, only when you cover them completly . Do you have a specific name ?

Comment: Try (now I have had a chance to look through my references) the MAX44000.

Comment: Great thanks ! a little bit expensive for mass production but great. If you have more you are welcome :)

Comment: A google search for "infra-red proximity chip" throws up a few more, such as the Si1102 and the GP2Y0A21YK

Comment: Yea... there are a lot more on Mouser, I was looking for something popular that people already using. Thanks.

Comment: Another example, which is more integrated: VCNL4010 - Adafruit do it as a module, so I can imagine there is plenty of support and code examples.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you try an [APDS-9960](https://docs.broadcom.com/docs/AV02-4191EN) based solution, this works out to several inches.
The chip is about $2 in qty[enter link description here](https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=apds9960), and is very reasonable as a small board solution available from Sparkfun or on Ebay, prices from $4 -$16.

[image]

I've used several of these $4 Ebay modules and they work just great.